# How do I prevent Tk from adding space?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I would like to draw tick marks on the side of a progressbar.

example:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

TickValue=15
#TickValue=85

ttk.Label(mainframe, text='%2i-' % TickValue).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=(N,E), pady=(100-TickValue-13))

pbar= ttk.Progressbar(mainframe, value=15, orient=VERTICAL, length=100)
pbar.grid(row=1, column=2,  sticky=(N, W))

root.mainloop()
```

TickValue=85 looks pretty fine, but TickValue=15 seems to push the height of the row to the south. The window has a big and ugly border. How can I prevent that?

(My code is mainly copy-pasted from http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The row is increasing in size because, by default, `pady` adds padding both above and below the widget. When `TickValue` is 15, `pady` is 72, for a total cell height of 144 plus however tall the actual label is. You can independently specify the top and bottom padding by passing a two element tuple to the parameter.

Change

```
pady=(100-TickValue-13)
```

to

```
pady=(100-TickValue-13, 0)
```

Now there should only be top padding, and no bottom padding.

[image]